# Prove that $\lim_{n} x_{n} = a \; \land\; \lim_{n} y_{n} = \infty \implies \lim_{n} (x_{n}-y_{n}) = -\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

By using the deifiniton of the limit of a sequence, prove that 
$$\lim_{n} x_{n} = a \; \land \; \lim_{n} y_{n} = \infty \implies \lim_{n} (x_{n}-y_{n}) = -\infty $$ 
where $a \in \mathbb R.$

I am still learning the basics of the sequences and limits and I have puzzled with this problem for a while now and unfortunately I still do not have any idea where to start. Maybe someone can provide me with any tips or hints, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: first prove that the sequence $x_n$ is uniformly bounded i.e. that there is a constant $C\in\mathbb R$ such that $x_n\le C$ for all $n$

Comment: What do you know about limits in order to find proper help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\bullet \forall M>0, \space\exists n_0>0 \text{ such that } \forall n>n_0\implies y_n>M$

$\bullet \forall ε>0, \space\exists n_1>0 \text{ such that } \forall n>n_1\implies |x_n - a|<ε \text{ or else written } a - ε< x_n < a+ε.$

From the last one you can prove that $x_n$ is bounded. So, $|x_n|<c$ for some $c>0$. Then by taking M' = c - M:

$$\forall M'<0, \exists n_0>0 \text{ such that } \forall n>n_0 \implies x_n - y_n < c - M = M'$$

So, by definition, we have $lim_{x\to \infty}(x_n - y_n) = -\infty$